# Insert distinct values only for one column

Tags: php, mysql

Say, I have a table with five columns `col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4` and `user_id`. Now, I have an array of `user_id` values, say a thousand. I want to insert thousand of records where only distinct column value is `user_id`. If there is a simplier way rather than make a thousand of ('col1value','col2value','col3value','col4value',someUserId) and concatenate them in single `insert into tbl (col1,col2,col3,col4,user_id) values` query?

**Update:** I guess it needs some clarification

So here's simple example. Let's say I have an `events` table with fields `event` and `user_id`. Some `call` event occurs for users with id 1, 2, 5, 101, 233, 422 and 1000. So I need to insert 7 records into table so it should look like

```
+-------+---------+
| event | user_id |
|-------|---------|
|  call |       1 |
|  call |       2 |
|  call |       5 |
|  call |     101 |
|  call |     233 |
|  call |     422 |
|  call |    1000 |
+-------+---------+
```

I want to do it as efficiently database-wise as possible. So far, I think I have to make such SQL query:

```
insert into events (event,user_id) values ('call',1),('call',2),('call',5),('call',101),('call',233),('call',422),('call',1000);
```

then perform a single query

But maybe there is some more simple and efficient way? Maybe something with SQL parameters or such?

Comment: Put your insert statement inside a loop. We can't give you any code suggestions unless you post your code for us to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your question that you have a high number of different `user_id` values that you want to insert, but for each new record you want the same values for `col1`, `col2`, `col3` and `col4`.

The easiest way to achieve this would be to set a `DEFAULT` value for each of the columns:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable CHANGE `col1` `col1` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1234
```

This sets the default value for `col1` to `1234`. I assumed the column to be of data type `INTEGER`, you need to change it accordingly.

If changing the table is not an option for you, then you could still build an insert statement that would insert all records in a single transaction:

```
$user_ids = array(5,6, 7, 8, 9, 10); // these are the user ids you want to insert
$default_vals = array(1, 2, 3, 4); // These are the default values used for col1, col2, col3 and col4

$con = new mysqli('mydomain', 'myuser', 'mypw', 'mydb');

$rows = array();
foreach ($user_ids as $id)
    $rows[] = "(".implode(',', $default_vals).",$id)";
$sql = "INSERT INTO mytbl (col1, col2, col3, col4, id) VALUES " . implode(',', $rows) . ";";

$con->query($sql);
```

Or, if for academic reason you'd rather write a single `INSERT` statement to do the whole job, you could write:

```
INSERT INTO mytbl (col1, col2, col3, col4, id)
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT 1, 2, 3, 4) AS DEFAULT_VALS,
  (SELECT 5
   UNION SELECT 6
   UNION SELECT 7
   UNION SELECT 8
   UNION SELECT 9) AS USER_IDS
```

However, the last approach really isn't very nice. Neither in terms of readability nor of performance.

---

**Edit**
I made a quick benchmark for you:

- Inserting 10k different records like in my PHP sample took *1.5086660385132 seconds* on my webserver.
- The `SELECT INTO` approach with 10k `UNION`s took *3.3481941223145 seconds*.

Easy choice, though.

Comment: Yes, the second approach looks like what I need, except I am not sure how efficiently MySQL deals with select unions even for defined values. But when number of constant columns and their size is high it might well worth it!

Comment: @kerby: The approach using `UNION`s is much slower and that's no surprise. `INSERT INTO` with many records is a very common scenario so you may assume that databases are optimized for such kind of transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
INSERT INTO tbl (col1,col2,col3,col4,user_id)
VALUES 
  (1,2,3,4,1000),
  (2,3,4,5,1000),
  (6,7,8,9,1000),
  (1,2,3,4,1234),
  (4,3,2,1,1235);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create unique index on `user_id` field. use `INSERT IGNORE` or `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` for ignoring duplicate insertion of `user_id`.

For details, kindly refer MySQL documentation.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html